# Change the text size depend of div width

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, frontend

I would like to change the size of font in container, depend of container wide, using CSS.
Parent container- a flexbox with flexbox children's that I want define to a breakpoint -

for example: if the container width size above 1000px, change the font size of the children div's to 20px. if the container size below 1000px - stay the font size of the children 25px.

I don't want to using media query because its not depends of screen size - it depends the width container size.

Comment: Please provide the code example you have come up with so far.

Comment: Check https://moderncss.dev/container-query-solutions-with-css-grid-and-flexbox/